# MassTransit is messing with my string data

Tags: c#, string, datetime, serialization, masstransit

Here's the test:

```
        var bus = ServiceBusFactory.New(c =>
                                        {
                                            c.DisablePerformanceCounters();
                                            c.UseRabbitMq();
                                            c.ReceiveFrom("rabbitmq://localhost/qqq");
                                        });
        bus.SubscribeHandler((Order o) => Console.WriteLine(o.Date));
        bus.Publish(new Order
                    {
                        Date = "1994-11-05T13:15:30Z"
                    });
```

Here's my Order class (Date property is of string type!):

```
public class Order
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

I expected the content of Date to be displayed, but here's the actual output:

```
11/05/1994 13:15:30
```

So, does MassTransit just try to convert every string he received into DateTime and then format it the way it wants, or what?

**UPD**: Using of XmlSerializer instead of Json didn't solve the problem. Here's the part of message I saw in RabbitMQ:

```
<date>1994-11-05T13:15:30Z</date>
```

And the message I received in app is altered in the same way again:

```
11/05/1994 13:15:30
```

**UPD2**: I've tested the serializer (Json.NET):

```
var panda = new Panda
                    {
                        Birthday = "1994-11-05T13:15:30Z"
                    };
Console.Out.WriteLine(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Panda>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(panda)).Birthday);
```

Output is the string "as is", so it seems that the problem is not with serializer.

Comment: "Date property is of string type" - Why?

Comment: Let's say it's representing data which I received from an external source, and I'd like to parse it into typed object some time later. It doesn't relate to my question, however.

Comment: I think you'll find it is related....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Created a MassTransit issue for it: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/197.

JSON.NET (5.0.6) does fail to translate properly.

```
[TestFixture]
public class IsoDateSerializationTest
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        JToken jtoken = JObject.Parse(@"{ IsoDate: ""1994-11-05T13:15:30Z"" }");
        Type deserializeType = typeof (MessageWithIsoDate);
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        object obj;

        using (var jsonReader = new JTokenReader(jtoken))
        {
            obj = serializer.Deserialize(jsonReader, deserializeType);
        }

        MessageWithIsoDate msg = obj as MessageWithIsoDate;
        Assert.That(msg.IsoDate, Is.EqualTo("1994-11-05T13:15:30Z"));
    }
}

public class MessageWithIsoDate
{
    public String IsoDate { get; set; }
}
```

Note: XML fails as well because MT just uses JSON.NET to deserialize XML as well. Apparently a lot faster than most XML serializers. Using BSON, Binary, or VersionOneXml all behave properly.

Comment: please see my update. also, I believe that this is really strange behavior for the transport to alter messages. I just want to receive my messages exactly the way I sent them, why should I be concerned about serialization specific stuff?

Comment: I created an issue. If you have something more to add, I would weigh in there.